# Reducing elements height in CSS animation is slightly delayed. Why?

Tags: html, css, animation, height, dimension

By default CSS animations are run immediately when the page loads, however they can be delayed using the `animation-delay` property. When the below snippet is run the rectangle doesn't shrink vertically until after a few seconds have already passed.

Why does it appear to "wait" like this and how might I fix it?

```css
/* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ INITIAL /////////////////////////////// */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
}

/* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ ANIMATIONS ///////////////////////////// */

.contract-ht {
  animation-name: contract-height;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes contract-height {
  100% {
    max-height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="contract-ht">shrink me vertically</p>
```

**EDIT:** I've added a snippet with a scale transform next to the height animation so side by side the height animation can be seen to start considerably slower than the `scale` animation. The leftmost animation almost begins as the right is finishing. I want the left to visibly start shrinking at the same time the right does. They both have the same duration, why does `max-height` based animation delay when I'm using no `animation-delay`?

**Snippet below**

```css
/* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ INITIAL /////////////////////////////// */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
}

/* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ ANIMATIONS ///////////////////////////// */

.contract-ht {
  animation-name: contract-height;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes contract-height {
  100% {
    max-height: 0;
  }
}

/* added these two css rules below */
.scale-ht {
  animation-name: scale-height;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes scale-height {
  100% {
    transform: scaleY( 0 );
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="contract-ht">shrink me vertically</p>

<!-- added the element below -->
<p class="scale-ht">scale my height</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have given `animation-duration: 2s;` so it will take 2 seconds to get the 100% transition to finish. Just reduce it like below to get decrease the delay. if you remove the transition duration it will show the immediate result

```css
/* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ INITIAL /////////////////////////////// */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
}

/* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ ANIMATIONS ///////////////////////////// */

.contract-ht {
  animation-name: contract-height;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes contract-height {
  100% {
    max-height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="contract-ht">shrink me vertically</p>
```

Comment: Your snippet still hangs up for a second before you see it moving. My question is why does the height behave in this way yet if I were to change the color or opacity the animation would start as soon as the browser loaded. This may have something to do with padding. Would you like me to provide an example of a regular animation next to it?

Comment: see the snippet now. it wont hang. I have updated the reason also

Comment: Your current example doesn't seem to move at all. Please see my updated question though, I gave a side by side example of what I'm talking about and the last animation definitely appears to start way sooner than the `height` one.